# Powershell: Deduping an array

Tags: powershell, arraylist, deduplication

I have a pipe delimited flat file from which I need to deduplicate the entries based on an object, to be specific a part of file is:

```
"001A"|"1"|"*"||"A"|"504367667"|"1"|"2005-06-10-16.57.23.000000"|
"001A"|"1"|"*"||"A"|"504367667"|"1"|"2005-10-24-16.52.29.000000"|
"001A"|"1"|"*"||"A"|"504367667"|"1"|"2007-12-13-15.48.47.000000"|
"001A"|"1"|"*"||"A"|"504367667"|"1"|"2008-12-09-17.10.39.000000"|
"001B"|"1"|"*"||"B"|"800026800"|"1"|"2005-08-08-10.48.16.000000"|
"001C"|"1"|"*"||"C"|"490349139"|"1"|"2006-01-19-12.03.08.000000"|
"001C"|"1"|"*"||"C"|"490349139"|"1"|"2009-03-12-15.08.11.000000"|
```

The first field is ID and last field is a timestamp, I want to deduplicate the entries such that only the latest timestamp entry is kept for each ID. So, The output that I need should be:

```
"001A"|"1"|"*"||"A"|"504367667"|"1"|"2008-12-09-17.10.39.000000"|
"001B"|"1"|"*"||"B"|"800026800"|"1"|"2005-08-08-10.48.16.000000"|
"001C"|"1"|"*"||"C"|"490349139"|"1"|"2009-03-12-15.08.11.000000"|
```

**I read the file and stored the entries in an array with distinct object names, then I tried**

```
$inputdeduped = $inputfilearray | Sort-Object Date
$inputdeduped = $inputdeduped | Select-Object ID -Unique
```

hoping that once the date is sorted, get-unique cmdlet used as -unique here would either pick either the first or last of the duplicated entry in the sorted array so depending on that I would sort the date in either desc or asc order, however it doesn't and randomly picks one entry.

**Please help me out guys or help me understand how the get-unique cmdlet works.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
  $newInputdeduped =  $inputfilearray | sort id, date -ascending | group -Property id |
     select @{n="GroupedList"; e={ $_.group | select -first 1 }} |
     select -expa list
```

This is what I do with your example data after saving it as a txt file:

```
> $a = Import-Csv -Header "id","n1","n2","v1","n3","n4","n5","date"  -Path .\c.txt -delimiter '|'

> $a | ft -AutoSize

id   n1 n2 v1 n3 n4        n5 date
--   -- -- -- -- --        -- ----
001A 1  *     A  504367667 1  2005-06-10-16.57.23.000000
001A 1  *     A  504367667 1  2005-10-24-16.52.29.000000
001A 1  *     A  504367667 1  2007-12-13-15.48.47.000000
001A 1  *     A  504367667 1  2008-12-09-17.10.39.000000
001B 1  *     B  800026800 1  2005-08-08-10.48.16.000000
001C 1  *     C  490349139 1  2006-01-19-12.03.08.000000
001C 1  *     C  490349139 1  2009-03-12-15.08.11.000000

> $b = $a | sort id, date -ascending | group -Property id | select @{n="list";e={ $_.group | select -first 1  }} | select -expa list

    > $b | ft -AutoSize

id   n1 n2 v1 n3 n4        n5 date
--   -- -- -- -- --        -- ----
001C 1  *     C  490349139 1  2009-03-12-15.08.11.000000
001B 1  *     B  800026800 1  2005-08-08-10.48.16.000000
001A 1  *     A  504367667 1  2008-12-09-17.10.39.000000
```

Comment: Dint work, It gives out a blank file. I can understand that your solution would group the sorted input by IDs and then in the third pipe you are selecting the first row of the group however I dont understand whats happening in the last 2 pipes.

Comment: `group-object` return an array of custom objects , with the two `select-object` I rebuilt an array like the one piped in. I can't figure how you have built the `$InputFilearray`.